# rpy2 version built against one R version but running linked to another

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am receiving errors when using rpy2. I think the main issue is that rpy2 links to an old R version which is probably not existing on my system anymore.

I installed rpy2 a while ago and probably had an older R version at that time. I tried to solve the problem by reinstalling rpy2 but without success.

```
python3 -m rpy2.tests
```

leads to

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Warnmeldung:

warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: In local({ :
warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning:  nicht passende Bytecode Versionen; nutze eval

warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Fehler in !value : ungültiger Argumenttyp

warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Zusätzlich: 
warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Paket ‘methods’ wurde unter R Version 3.4.4 erstellt 

warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Warnmeldungen:

warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 1: Paket ‘datasets’ wurde unter R Version 3.4.4 erstellt 

warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 2: Paket ‘utils’ wurde unter R Version 3.4.4 erstellt 

warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
rpy2 version: 2.9.5
- built against R version: 3-4.4--74408
- running linked to R version: R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
E
======================================================================
ERROR: __main__ (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/tests.py", line 43, in load_tests
suite_robjects = loader.discover('robjects', pattern, rpy_root)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in discover
__import__(start_dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/robject.py", line 52, in <module>
class RObjectMixin(object):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/robject.py", line 66, in RObjectMixin
__show = rpy2.rinterface.baseenv.get("show")
LookupError: 'show' not found

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I guess the main issue is the following:

built against R version: 3-4.4--74408 is as expected my current R version. This should be correct.
But running linked to R version: R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) seems wrong. I am pretty sure such a version is not existing on my system anymore. But it might be the version that I had when installing rpy2 for the first time.

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 and I am using Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) , R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) and rpy2-2.9.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:
I am even more puzzeled now.

```
python3 -m rpy2.situation
```

gives

```
Python version:
3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Looking for R's HOME:
    Environment variable R_HOME: None
    Calling `R RHOME`: /usr/lib/R
    InstallPath in the registry: *** Only available on Windows ***
R version:
    In the PATH: R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
    Used to build rpy2: 3-4.4--74408
Additional directories to load R packages from:
None
```

This looks completely fine. I have still no idea why rpy2 links to R version 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following to obtain information about how rpy2 was built and where is the R version it finds at runtime:

```
python -m rpy2.situation
```

In addition to this, you may want to check whether you have set the environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD` as it might influence which R shared library is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, it says /usr/bin/python: No module named rpy2.situation, but I guess you meant python3 -m rpy2.situation. I added the result to my starting post. But the result looks like how it should be. I see no hint why it links wrongly.

Comment: I added a line to my answer. You will also want to check whether your are forcing the system's hand with environment variables.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH was indeed set and a simple unset solved the problem, thanks.